# Dom force rendering of an element In Electron

Tags: javascript, dom, refresh, electron, chromium

I need to change part of the text of a Button before starting a process (twain scan) and rewriting the original text after the process finished.
It seems I need to force in some way the rendering of the button before the process start and I don't know how (I tried with setTimeout but with no success).
I try a simple test with an alert in place of the process and it's doing the same thing. It's working if I put a breakpoint before the alert but not without bkpt.I would like really what is behind this problem and a way of working around in a Long-lasting solution (in case of browser update).
Is this strange behavior special to chromium?

```
<div id="hidebtn" class=" col-sm-11 ">
  <button id="btn-scan" type="button" class="btn btn-primary  col-sm-offset-2   col-sm-8">SCAN<br><span id ="span-piece-std">DOCUMENT</span></button>
</div

var textBtnScan="";

document.querySelector('#btn-scan').onclick = function () {  
    debutScan();        
    alert("something is processing");
    finScan();       
  };      


function debutScan(){ 
    textBtnScan =  $("#span-piece-std").text();
    $("#span-piece-std").text(" Running......");
}
function finScan(){
    $("#span-piece-std").text(textBtnScan);  
}
```

Comment: I made a test outside of Electron and it work with Firefox but not with Chrome

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same issue. Did you resolve it? I'm using Chrome. It's VERY frustrating. I can see the DOM changing in the Chrome console window but the screen remains unchanged. It's horrible!

Comment: I don't remember exactly why but I eventually added another buton btn-scan-en-cours surimposed to the other one with this piece of code document.querySelector('#btn-scan').onclick = function (evt) {
              
          $('#btn-scan').hide();
          $('#btn-scan-en-cours').show();
          setTimeout(function () {
            .....process which do something         
            $('#btn-scan').show();
            $('#btn-scan-en-cours').hide();          
          }, 50);
        };

Comment: Thx. They really need to make this easier!